# Accessing Rails model information across belongs_to / has_many relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been reviewing the rails documentation and I'm stuck with an issue of trying to access data that is inside a has_many / belongs_to relationship.  I have 3 data models that look like the following:

```
class Cuisine < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :providers
validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end

class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :cuisine
    has_many :lunches
    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    validates :cuisine, presence: true
end

class Lunch < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :provider
    default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
    validates :date, presence: true, uniqueness: true

end
```

My main question is - how can I display data from the lunches model that is associated with a provider? I.e.  provider.lunches.lunchscore *within* the *provider's* show.html.erb?

For more context, this is my providers_controller.rb:

```
  def show
    @provider = Provider.find(params[:id])
    @lunches = @provider.lunches
    @cuisine = @provider.cuisine
  end
```

I am editing the show.html.erb for the provider view, and I'm looking to display data related to the provider.

Having followed a tutorial from [railstutorial.org](http://rails-4-0.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts#sec-showing_microposts) I included a partial that is based off (I believe) a collection.  So, views/providers/show.html.erb has this layout:

```
<% if @provider.lunches.any? %>
<h3> Total Lunches - (<%= @provider.lunches.count %>) </h3>
<%= render @lunches %> 
<br>
<% end %>
```

The @lunches variable (which is a collection, I think?) then loads a _lunch.html.erb partial, which is located in apps/views/lunches/_lunch.html.erb, with the following:

```
<ul>
    <span class="date-score"><%= number_to_percentage(lunch.lunchscore * 100, precision: 0) %> </span>
    <span class="date-list"> <%= link_to lunch.date.strftime("%A %B %e, %G"), lunch_path(lunch.id) %> - <%= link_to @provider.name, lunch_path(lunch.id) %> Likes <%= lunch.liked %> </span>

</ul>
```

This actually works great - until I  want to load data *outside* of the if statement (and outside of the partial entirely) and actually contain it directly within app/views/providers/show.html.erb.  For example, the lunch model has the following attributes:

```
:date, :liked, :disliked, :enough, :not_enough, :provider_id
```

**My Question:** How can I access and aggregate the attributes from within the providers/show.html.erb model, if I don't want to iterate and print every value via the if statement in the partial?

If I try something basic like include this in the provider show.html.erb file, I error out:

```
<%= @provider.lunches.lunchscore.average %>
```

Thanks for your help.  I apologize if I use the wrong nomenclature (i.e. data model attribute or hashes as collections) I'm just learning and also new to Stack Exchange.  Feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variables you set in your controller prepended by an @ are called instance variables and are available in your view.

`@provider = Provider.find(params[:id])` returns a single record

`@lunches = @provider.lunches` returns an [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html)

When you call `@provider.lunches.lunchscore`, you are calling an instance method that is to be called on a single Lunch record but right now you are dealing with a Relation of Lunch records.

For example, to select single lunch records, you could loop over the lunches

```
@lunches.each do |lunch|
    lunch.lunchscore
end
```

or you could only select the first record in the relation

```
@lunches.first.lunchscore
```

I hope this clarifies the difference between a record and a relation.

Comment: This clarifies the difference, but how would I access / add up all the different lunchscores across the relation? Something like:

`@lunches.each do |lunch|
@totallunchscores = totallunchscores + lunch.lunchscore
end`

Comment: `counter = 0 @lunches.each do |lunch| counter += lunch.lunchscore end`

Comment: When I use your first example `@lunches.each do |lunch|
    lunch.lunchscore
end`  it actually outputs all the data from what is stored in lunch - dates, liked, disliked, created on, etc. If I remove the .lunchscore from the loop, it has the same output.   Sorry for the late reply, I appreciate the help.

Comment: `@lunches.each do` and `end` need to be wrapped by `<% %>` and `lunch.lunchscore` by `<%= %>`

Comment: Great, that worked for outputting all of the different scores (your first example) but the second example (with counter) outputs the consecutive values - I only want the "total" of the addition (and I want to divide by number of lunches) so how do I avoid having the sequential output of the addition posted to the page?  This code: `<% counter = 0 
@lunches.each do |lunch| %>

<%= counter += lunch.lunchscore %>
 
 <% end %>`

Outputs: `0.8125 <snip of numbers> 6.6969994398043395 7.421137370838823` and I'd rather it just output 7.42 (and have it divide by number of entries / lunches)

Comment: Actually, solved this myself! This worked: 

`<% counter = 0 %>
<% @lunches.each do |lunch| %>
<% counter += lunch.lunchscore %> 
<% end %>

<%= counter / @provider.lunches.count %>`